# MySQL server has gone away in Symfony 2.8 (only in stag, not in dev)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I run Symfony 2.8.

When I perform one specific action I get this errors:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\Data\Repos\main\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php on line 91
>
> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): Error reading result set's header in C:\Data\Repos\main\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php on line 91

But this happens only on my stag environment. In my dev env it does not. Before you ask: cache is clear (I killed the directory). My stag env is very similar to the dev one, and when it comes to DB it's exactly the same.

The action I'm performing takes some time, so could it be a timeout issue? Maybe I have different timeouts in stag and dev?

Any clue?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html

Comment: I get that error when executing many long queries through symfony with doctrine. The memory was being all used up and I had to manually manage the memory by calling $em->clear() periodically.

Comment: Did you try to set `wait_timeout` in `my.cnf` file? Find more information here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout.

The second thing is to increase the  `max_allowed_packet`.

Comment: The 'max_allowed_packet' did the trick, apparently. I have to test it a bit more, but so far so good! Thank you all!

Answer (score -1):

Seems this was solved on the comments, please take a look

> Did you try to set wait_timeout in my.cnf file? Find more information here >dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/…. The second thing is to increase the max_allowed_packet. >– Ahmad Mar 15 '17 at 13:56
>
> The 'max_allowed_packet' did the trick, apparently. I have to test it a bit more, but so >far so good! Thank you all! – Sergio Negri Mar 15 '17 at 15:28

Posted here for the users that scan just the possible answers and might miss the comments.